# Integral of the Normal Characteristic Function

Tags: calculus, integration, normal-distribution, characteristic-functions

The characteristic function of the $N$-variate Normal distribution is
$$\forall \mathbf{t} \in \mathbb{R}^N \quad
\psi(\mathbf{t}) \equiv \mathbb{E}\left(
  e^{i\mathbf{t}X}\right) =
  \exp \left( i{ }^t\boldsymbol\mu \mathbf{t} - \frac{1}{2}{
  }^t\mathbf{t}\boldsymbol\Sigma\mathbf{t}\right)$$

Is there any way to compute its integral on a symmetric cube? Suppose $(q_1,\ldots,q_N)\in\mathbb{R}_+^N$, then I want to calculate

$$I(q_1,\ldots,q_N)\equiv \int_{-q_1}^{q_1}\cdots\int_{-q_N}^{q_N} \psi(\mathbf{t})$$

I am particularly interested in the bivariate case ($N=2$) with
$$\mu=\begin{pmatrix}\mu_1\\\mu_2\end{pmatrix}
\quad
\Sigma=\begin{pmatrix}1 & \rho \\ \rho & 1 \end{pmatrix}
$$

Edit: If no exact solutions exist, approximations for $min(q_i) \gg 1$ are of interest. In any case, references would be greatly appreciated.